# Setting LCD gamma / contrast (IntelliJ IDEA, JDK 8)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-2d, antialiasing, text-rendering

I am having trouble with anti-aliased text in IntelliJ IDEA. That thing for some reason ships with its own version of OpenJDK 8. Anyway... sub-pixel aliasing is acceptable with dark-on-bright text:

[image]

But the gamma is wrong for bright-on-dark text:

[image]

Which means in this scheme, text looks as if it was bold-face and horizontally smeared/fuzzy.

Is it possible to specify a system property or hack the system otherwise to change the gamma for AA interpolation towards darker colours? I already choose a very fine font (FicaCode Light), there is simply no font that shows less bold on this computer (Linux with Gnome 3, 1920x1080 display).

---

**Edit:** I am really looking for a way to control the AA gamma. I have not used IDEA 2017.1 EAP, but the release version which comes already with the 'fixed' bundled tuned version 1.8.0_112, that is mentioned in the gist comment. If I download that version, I get exactly the same pixel output as the two images above. These are the `idea64.jvmoptions`:

## custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Djava2d.font.loadFontConf=false
```

Adding or removing the last property simply makes zero difference, also changing from `lcd` to `on` or `off` has zero effect.

Compare these pictures to the regular OpenJDK 1.8.0_121 that I installed via Debian:

[image]

Clearly here the AA is broken (at 1:1 it looks totally coloured). So I think the subpixel rendering of the bundled version is basically *correct*. Only it uses the wrong gamma for light text on dark background.

---

**Edit:** After more investigation, the problem boils down to this: I can use a custom `font.conf` file with `hintstyle` between `hintslight`, `hintmedium` and `hintfull`. For slight hinting, the font looks balanced in terms of aspect ratio, but the anti-aliasing has wrong gamma, and so the font lines are thick (everything looks bold face). For medium or full hinting, the font appears more thin-lined and sharp, but now the aspect ratio is broken, the font is too wide.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/CrazyCoder/0d9e54f450000d3fb6edcbda6d9788be.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks - I was in fact already using the updated JDK that the gist mentions, as I installed the release version of IDEA. So my question is, if it is possible to tune the AA gamma value that is used by the renderer.

Comment: JDK in gist is not the same as in the release version.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried that one as well, but output looks completely identical to first two images. Also toggling the `-Djava2d.font.loadFontConf=false` has no effect at all. It seems the rendering is hardcoded, using `off` instead of `lcd` doesn't have any effect, either.

Comment: Your font is too large to be affected by the settings. Either create custom [font.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) or modify the one inside JetBrains Runtime `lib/fonts/font.conf` and use `-Djava2d.font.loadFontConf=true` to load this customized config.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206607445-A-fix-for-font-ugliness-under-Linux?sort_by=votes

Comment: @SamuelTulach are you suggesting I should build my own version of OpenJDK?

Comment: Has the dark theme solved your problem?

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but I came across this a while ago.
https://www.reddit.com/r/IntelliJIDEA/comments/gp1hup/jetbrainsruntime_patched_for_linux_hidpi_font/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, although zooming into the current rendering (IC 2020.3) looks similar to the original screenshot:

[image]

I no longer feel this looks too bold or blurry. Perhaps it's the slight change of font (using JetBrains Mono now).

Answer (score 1):

You said that the normal `openJDK` works the way you want him to work, correct?

If true, Why don't you change the JDK `IntelliJ` use?
I believe it is platform `SDK` in preferences.